# String "Array" before image content element using Ext:perfectlightbox

Tags: typo3

I'm using the extensions **perfectlightbox** (version 4.0.2) but instead of wrapping the image with the lightbox link there is the string *Array* printed out before the image:

```
Array<img src="fileadmin/_processed_/..._818dbe2012.jpg" width="240" height="97" alt="" border="0">
```

I'm using TYPO3 7.6 LTS. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in version 4.0.2 of perfectlightbox although the compatibility says it works with TYPO3 7.6. 
The developer [made a fix](https://github.com/beniediek/perfectlightbox/issues/2) at GitHub but did not yet released a new version for the TYPO3 Extensions Repository.
Here is what you can do so far:

1. Go to the [GitHub project of this extension](https://github.com/beniediek/perfectlightbox)
2. Download the extension as ZIP file (click 'Clone or download' on right top)
3. Clean your directory typo3conf/ext/perfectlightbox
4. Copy all files from ZIP into the cleaned directory
5. Clean caches

All should be fine now. The version number is still the same but if the developer will release a new version into TYPO3 Extension Repository this fix will be included so it's okay to patch it this way.